# Get day from a Date - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, calendar, getdate

in my program when I click on a calendar I am getting the "selectedDate" variable changed. Like if I click on 4/6/2021 the value of selectedDate = 04-06-2021, Like if I click on 14/7/2021 the value of selectedDate = 14-07-2021.

I need to get which day of the week the dates are. I am trying in this way:

```
        <View>
           
            <H1 color={color.white}>{days[selectedDate.getDay()]}</H1>
          
         </View>
```

I need to get which day of the week is the selected date. this syntax is giving an error "Property 'getDay' does not exist on type 'string'"

Comment: You need to convert it to Javascript time by using ````new Date('mm-dd-yyyy')````

Answer (score 1):

Use moment https://momentjs.com/

import moment inside your file

```
moment().format('dddd');
```

this is the method to get day from a given date

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment(https://momentjs.com/) for this. With the help of moment we can get date in different formats. I hope you this will help